# Package name without main.java in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I develop my project in Eclipse with standard Maven directory layout. Sources are in src/main/java/com/mycompany directory. And it is required to put my source classes in package main.java.com.mycompany.
When I build executable jar-file, I have to define the main class in Manifest.MF like:

```
    Main-Class: main.java.com.mycompany.MyMainClass
```

But I saw in a lot of examples (like configuring the mainClass attribute in maven-assembly-plugin or maven-jar-plugin) that class names are specified without main.java part. I just want to have

```
    Main-Class: com.mycompany.MyMainClass
```

I can't figure out how I can achieve this because I'm completely novice in Maven.

Comment: The given main.java package is not related to the src/main/java location. If this is needed than your configuration in Eclipse (m2e) etc. is wrong.

Comment: I haven't used any plugins for Eclipse (m2e) or for Maven like maven-eclipse yet, just have built projects with mvn from command line.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Maven's default directory layout differs from the layout Eclipse uses when you create a new Java project.

It's actually pretty simple. When you create a new Java project, Eclipse creates a folder named 'src' on your filesystem, where you should put your source code. Additionally, Eclipse configures this folder as a 'source folder'. Every folder you create in this folder will represent a Java package.

What Maven wants is a little bit different. Maven likes you to have a 'src/main/java' folder with the 'java' subfolder configured to be a source folder. Hence, all folders created under this java folder will represent Java packages.

You can manage your source folders in Eclipse from your project properties. Right click your project, select 'build path -> configure build path'. In the popup open the 'source' tab. Now, remove 'src' as a source folder and replace it with 'src/main/java'.

Now Eclipse will recognize your packages as com.mycompany instead of main.java.com.mycompany.

I always use the maven-eclipse plugin to generate my eclipse project and classpath files from the commmand line. I'm not a big fan of m2e.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try updating the maven project. 
Right click on the project > Maven > Update Maven Project.

Answer (score 3):

Use m2e if you are using eclipse. The eclipse workspace is configured incorrectly for a maven project